# Spawn a new thread for item in list

Tags: python, multithreading, list, iteration

newbie here, thank you for taking the time to look at this!

I am trying to create a script which reads a list of IP address', and then spawns a new thread for each IP address in the list. The reason for spawning a new thread is to make the script as fast and lightweight as possible.

The problem i'm having is that my script takes around 4 seconds to complete, where it will only ping 12 IP address'. I am looking to ping a range of IP address' in under a second, so if anybody has any suggestions or tips I'm all ears!

```
import subprocess
import re
import threading


def get_ips():

        # Fill empty list with IP address 
        ips = []
        with open('C:\Python26\ARPips.prn','r')as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line[:-1]
                if line != "end":
                    ips.append(line)
            return ips

def ping():

    #Ping with "pingArgs" as the arguments
    ping = subprocess.Popen(pingArgs,
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True)

    #Get and parse output 
    out = ping.communicate()
    out = ''.join((out))
    lost = re.findall(r"Lost = (\d+)", out)
    minimum = re.findall(r"Minimum = (\d+)", out)
    maximum = re.findall(r"Maximum = (\d+)", out)
    avg = re.findall(r"Average = (\d+)", out)
    no =  re.findall(r"Sent = (\d+)", out)

    # Change output to integers
    lost = [int(x) for x in lost]
    minimum = [int(x) for x in minimum]
    maximum = [int(x) for x in maximum]
    avg = [int(x) for x in avg]
    no = [int(x) for x in no]

    # Format output for console
    print "%s \t \t %s \t \t%s \t \t %s \t \t%s" % (no, lost, maximum, minimum, avg)

def main():

    # grab IP address list
    ips = get_ips()

    # Header for output 
    print "Packets \t loss(%) \t Max(ms) \t Min(ms) \t Average(ms)"

    # Global variables for module
    global position, newIP, pingArgs
    position = 0

    # Loop through IP list and spawn new thread for each IP
    for i in ips:
        newIP = ips[position]
        position += 1
        pingArgs = ["ping", "-n", "1", "-l", "1", "-w", "100", newIP]
        t = threading.Thread(target= ping(), args = pingArgs)
        t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
t = threading.Thread(target= ping(), args = pingArgs)
```

You are executing `ping()` with no args and returning the result to `target`. This is not threaded behavior. You need to change this to:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=ping, args=(pingArgs,))
```

You will also need to modify your definition of `ping()` to accept arguments:

```
def ping(pingArgs):
```

There are a couple of other issues in your code, such as the `print` statements in `ping` (since the threads are asynchronous and printing to stdout is "non-atomic", your code will not reliably `print` your print statements in order.). Once you get your code working, I would recommend putting it on `codereview` for some further feedback.

Comment: Hey @Joel, thanks for replying! 

When I modified the line, I get the following error

TypeError: ping() takes no arguments (8 given) 

Do you have any recommendations as to how I get around this? Thanks again!

Comment: @TomO'Mara: See my edit. Notice that I've also slightly modified the 2nd line in my answer as well.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! your suggestion was correct! I'm sorry to reply with another question, so feel free to leave it as I will continue to research the problem, but do you have a link to point me in the right direction for fixing the unreliable output? (I'd upvote your answer if I had enough rep)  ): Thanks again!

Comment: One solution is to `append` your results to a global list and print the contents of the list once all of your threads are done. A better solution is described in this excellent article: https://medium.com/building-things-on-the-internet/40e9b2b36148

Comment: I can't thank you enough buddy! I really appreciate your help with this!!! *high five*